# Set Button.Tag in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, button, microsoft-metro

How do I set a string type or int type to a button in a metro app?

I have tried the below code,

```
<Button Name="oldlogs" Tag="old" 
        Content="New Logs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="819,660,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Click="showNewLogs"/>
```

but when I check

```
if (oldlogs.Tag == "old") {
                addedVal++;
                flag = 1;
                showLog(sender, e);
            }
```

The control doesnt enter the if loop! Kindly help through.

Comment: What is the content of Tag while debugging? Why do you need tag which describes button? p.s. if is not a loop.

Comment: I suggest you use a `public static bool Equals(string a,string b)` to compare to `String` objects.  It results in cleaner code.  The method is of course case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) stores an object.

You need to cast it to string and then compare it with "old" literal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had to typecast into string. It worked sweet.